# Is it possible to run P4wnP1 on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, git

im 13 years old and im from italy(my english isn't very good for this reason), for you is possible to run P4wnP1 (for ethical hacking purpose) on rpi 3 model B?

If the answer of that question is 'True', i' ve to modificate something in the package .git ?

Comment: What is P4wnP1?

Comment: "P4wnP1 is a highly customizable USB attack platform, based on a low cost Raspberry Pi Zero or Raspberry Pi Zero W." - According to its page on GitHub.